# Shortest path not returning correct solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, dijkstra, shortest-path

Been trying to implement Dijkstras algorithm in a user defined graph. But it keeps giving incorrect solutions. Anyway you guys can take a look and help me out?

[I have been trying to use this graph as my test graph where A is the start Node and G is the end node. It should return the path A,C,D,F,G, but it actually returns A,B,D,E,G. For some reason it skips out the C...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD0lM.png)

```
 def ShortestPath(self, Source, Dest):
    Distances = {}
    Previous = {}

    for EachNode in self.NodeList.keys():
        Distances[EachNode] = -1
        Previous[EachNode] = ""

    Distances[Source] = 0
    UnseenNodes = self.NodeList.keys()
    while len(UnseenNodes) > 0:
        ShortestDistance = None
        Node = ""
        for TempNode in UnseenNodes:
            if ShortestDistance == None:
                ShortestDistance = Distances[TempNode]
                Node = TempNode
            elif Distances[TempNode] < ShortestDistance:
                ShortestDistance = Distances[TempNode]
                Node = TempNode
        UnseenNodes.remove(Node)

        for Neighbour, NeighbourValue in self.NodeList[Node].Connections.items():
            NeighbourID = Neighbour.GetID()
            print NeighbourID
            if Distances[NeighbourID] < Distances[Node] + NeighbourValue:
                Distances[NeighbourID] = Distances[Node] + NeighbourValue
                Previous[NeighbourID] = Node

    print Previous
    Path = []
    Node = Dest
    while not (Node == Source):
        if Path.count(Node) == 0:
            Path.insert(0,Node)
            Node = Previous[Node]
        else:
            break
    Path.insert(0,Source)
    print Path
```

Comment: Btw have you tried to debug it? For example Pycharm has nice python debugger, can put breakpoints to each of your steps and investigate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if Distances[NeighbourID] < Distances[Node] + NeighbourValue:
```

Change the less-than sign to a greater-than sign, as you only want to replace the `Neighbor`'s distance with a smaller one. Furthermore, you must also make sure that you treat `Distance[i] == -1` as a separate case whenever you're trying to find the minimum distance.

The fixed code:

```
 def ShortestPath(self, Source, Dest):
    Distances = {}
    Previous = {}

    for EachNode in self.NodeList.keys():
        Distances[EachNode] = -1
        Previous[EachNode] = ""

    Distances[Source] = 0
    UnseenNodes = self.NodeList.keys()
    while len(UnseenNodes) > 0:
        ShortestDistance = None
        Node = ""
        for TempNode in UnseenNodes:
            if Distances[TempNode] == -1: continue
            if ShortestDistance == None:
                ShortestDistance = Distances[TempNode]
                Node = TempNode
            elif Distances[TempNode] < ShortestDistance:
                ShortestDistance = Distances[TempNode]
                Node = TempNode

        if ShortestDistance is None: break
        UnseenNodes.remove(Node)

        for Neighbour, NeighbourValue in self.NodeList[Node].Connections.items():
            NeighbourID = Neighbour.GetID()
            print NeighbourID
            if Distances[NeighbourID] == -1 or Distances[NeighbourID] > Distances[Node] + NeighbourValue:
                Distances[NeighbourID] = Distances[Node] + NeighbourValue
                Previous[NeighbourID] = Node

    print Previous
    Path = []
    Node = Dest
    while not (Node == Source):
        if Path.count(Node) == 0:
            Path.insert(0,Node)
            Node = Previous[Node]
        else:
            break
    Path.insert(0,Source)
    print Path
```

Comment: Yeah, that's working like a treat now. I didn't know about the continue statement you have used as well ! Thanks!